# How do I build a coffeescript project using browserify so it's fully require-able from the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, browserify

Basically I have a coffeescript project/module that I want to build using browserify and that should be usable from a browser.

For example, let's say I have this project structure:

```
myproject/
  foo.coffee
  bar.coffee
  index.js

  controllers/
    meow.coffee
```

I want to (for example) be able to do this in the browser:

```
<script>
  ctrl = require("myproject/controllers/meow")
  ctrl.initialize()
</script>
```

I've managed to build it like I would a normal nodejs module, by adding a package.js file and invoking this command:

```
browserify -t coffeeify --extension ".coffee" -r myproject -o static/js/myproject.js
```

I needed to use a javascript file (not a coffee file) as the project index, since that would be evaluated as javascript no matter what, but the rest of the files could be coffeescript files. This compiles and works great.

I can now do `require("myproject")` in the browser, but I still can't do `require("myproject/foo")`. It results in:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'myproject/foo'

Even though that same require call is successful inside `index.js`, and I've tested that it actually runs successfully in the browser, the require call will fail to find the module when called from the dev console.

Does anybody know how to compile a coffeescript project using browserify so that all the files inside it can be required from other javascript files in the browser?

Comment: try: `browserify -t coffeeify --extension ".coffee" -r myproject -r myproject/foo -o static/js/myproject.js`

Comment: @marcel Already tried, doesn't work. It seems to assume that `myproject/foo` is javascript (not coffeescript) and crash due to syntax errors

Comment: did you try it without `--extension ".coffee"`?

Comment: @marcel No... That would mean it can't find "myproject/foo.coffee", wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't know. i never used the `extension` option. BTW: it think it should be used like this: `--extension=".coffee"`